# Boost graph edge and vertex property adding

Tags: c++, boost, graph

Hi I am learning how to add properties to nodes and edges of the adjacency list of the Boost Graph Library. I am using the following code to add a distance of 3.1 to every edge:

```
typedef property < edge_weight_t, double >Weight;
using std::vector;
using Graph = adjacency_list<setS, vecS, undirectedS, Point, Weight>;
using vertex_descriptor = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

Graph lattuce; // add name of graph  

for (auto vd : make_iterator_range(vertices(lattuce))) {
    auto p = lattuce[vd];//pass number of vertice to p

    for (Point neighbour : {
            Point { p.x - 1, p.y - 1 }, Point { p.x - 1, p.y + 0 }, Point { p.x - 1, p.y + 1 },
            Point { p.x + 0, p.y - 1 }, Point { p.x + 0, p.y + 1 },
            Point { p.x + 1, p.y - 1 }, Point { p.x + 1, p.y + 0 }, Point { p.x + 1, p.y + 1 },
        })//for loop goes around all neighbours, 8 per vertex
    {
        if (is_valid(neighbour)&&(arrayA[neighbour.x][neighbour.y]==0))//if there is a neighbour then add edge(gets rid off non zeros)
            add_edge(nodes[neighbour.x][neighbour.y], vd, lattuce, 3.1);
    };
}
```

I get the following error

```
main.cpp:105: error: no matching function for call to 'add_edge(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<unsigned int> >::value_type&, unsigned int&, Graph&, double)'
                 add_edge(nodes[neighbour.x][neighbour.y], vd, lattuce, 3.1);
```

This is only a part of my code for brevity, it works when I don´t add the weight property and 3.1 value to the edges.

Any help or guidance wwould be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The invocation of `add_edge` that you need is `std::pair<edge_descriptor, bool>
add_edge(vertex_descriptor u, vertex_descriptor v,
         const EdgeProperties& p,
         adjacency_list& g)`. And that is not what you used. You may need to use `Weight(3.1)` instead of just `3.1`.

Comment: Why don't you show a SSCCE? I remember when I wrote that code for you, but I don't want to find out what changed :)

Comment: Hi thank you this helped! Also, thank you @sehe I'll look into writing SSCCEs

Comment: In this case, you could simply have built on the sample you got. I make it a point to post SSCCE answers (nearly all my answers have a "Live On Coliru" link - or several)